# if文の部分がエラーになるのですがなぜでしょうか？

Tags: java

```
class Solution{
    public static int vacationRental(int people, int day){
        // 関数を完成させてください
        if(day<=3) int perDay=80;
        else if(4<=day&&day<=9) int perDay=60;
        else int perDay=50;

        return Math.floor(people*perDay*day*1.12);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

変数`perDay`は使用される前に一度だけ宣言されている必要があります。
なので、classの先頭で`int perDay`を宣言し、各`if`,`else`節でそれを利用するだけにして上げます。

```
class Solution {
    public static int vacationRental(int people, int day){
        // 関数を完成させてください
        int perDay;
        if(day<=3) perDay=80;
        else if(4<=day&&day<=9) perDay=60;
        else perDay=50;

        return (int)Math.floor(people*perDay*day*1.12);
        
    }
}
```

だと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: 良かったです。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)も参照下さい